# ¿Cómo obtener un valor almacenado en el navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, asp.net-mvc, web

Desarrollo una aplicación en la cual renderizo una página dentro de un IFRAME, cuando se muestra la pagina esta almacena una llave en el navegador tal cual muestro en la imagen.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener este valor?

“Debo recalcar que mi aplicación está corriendo en `http://localhost:1405/Home`  y el valor que necesitó obtener viene desde https://cdn.c.sat.gob.gt  y el nombre del key es igual a `accesToken`”

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se puede hacer eso, está diseñado para evitarlo justamente.

Answer (score 1):

para extraer el `accessToken` necesitas usar `localStorage` (En javascript)

```js
localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
```

Lo que hace esto es buscar el identificador (en este caso `accessToken`) y la recoge.

Para comprobar que se obtuvo exitosamente puedes imprimirlo en consola

```js
let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
console.log(accessToken);
```

Sí todo sale bien, el valor debería mostrarse en consola.
Espero que te haya servido
Saludos!

Comment: No se puede realizar eso entre dos dominios distintos.  Fíjate en su imagen. La clave pertenece a otro dominio distinto al cual el está navegando. Piensa que ocurriría si esa misma clave estuviera almacenada en distintos dominios con distintos valores... ¿cual de ellas querria coger el localStorage.getItem()? ¿cómo accederias a una u otra con la misma clave?  Está pensado para que eso no pueda hacerse y evitar un churro de posibles vulnerabilidades.